# loop is not updating values on table, index wise

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, for-loop, indexing

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
//dd($users);
for($i=0; $i<$users ; $i++){
   
    $updated=DB::table('users')->where('latehours' , 0)->update(['latehours'=>$total_hours[$i]]);
    $updated=DB::table('users')->where('fine' , 0)->update(['fine'=>$fine[$i]]);
   }
```

I have table named as users I want to update two columns of it latehours and fine respectively, both column are updating but with first value of array's index, but my loop is not working.

[image]

arrays are $total_hours and $fine.
thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your array values ?

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 3
]  it is $total_hours array

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => 100
  1 => 200
  2 => 300
] it is $fine array

Comment: this is the expected result of your current code, what do you want to do??

Comment: I want to have array's  index 1 and index 2 values of both arrays at users 'id' 2 and 3

Comment: user 1 will get the `$total_hours` first index, user 2 will get the `$total_hours` second index and user 3 will get the `$total_hours` third index and so on?? what is your logic here actually??

Comment: you've understand my problem ,I am confused, can you tell what I code there to get the result I want. thanks

Comment: do your array has the same length of the user count??

Comment: yes, the length of array is same as length of user count.

Comment: then you have to loop through the user table, something like `$updated=DB::table('users')->where('id' , ($i + 1))->update(['latehours'=>$total_hours[$i]]);`

Comment: your business logic is not clear..can you provide your logic??

Comment: thankyou so much for your help, it works 

Comment: @zahidhasanemon it inputs starttime and endtime and fine_per_hour and compare it with clockin_time and clockout_time and then calculate total fine and latehours. respectively, now it is working with your help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $users = DB::table('users')->count();
   //dd($users);
   for($i=0; $i<$users ; $i++){
   
    $updated=DB::table('users')->where('latehours' , 0)->where('id' , ($i + 1))->update(['latehours'=>$total_hours[$i]]);
    $updatedd=DB::table('users')->where('fine' , 0)->where('id' , ($i + 1))->update(['fine'=>$fine[$i]]);
   // dd($updatedd);
   }
```

there was problem in it, that it was not iterating id so I put where condition of id where('id' , ($i+1)). now it is working perfectly. thanks all

[db table now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alVro.png)

Comment: It was iterating! After the first iteration,  where every user with latehours or fine 0 was updated, there were no users left with latehours or fine 0. That made it seem as if there was an iteration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your where conditions are not matched, hence it doesn't update your records.

Comment: it is updating the value as you see in picture I attached, but it is not updating index wise. means to say loop and array indexing is not working.